# Binance api get only USDT pairs - Achieve that by only getting data from symbol that has USDT as the last 4 letters

Tags: c#, api, xamarin, binance

I have a function here that gets the data from binance api but the problem is, it gets all the trading pairs. I only want to show the ones that ends with USDT in my picker. How do i do that?

```
        public class Crypto
        {
            public string symbol { get; set; }
            public string price { get; set; }
        }


        private async void GetSymbol()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price");
            var cryptoconverted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Crypto>>(response);
            var sorted = cryptoconverted.OrderBy(x => x.symbol).ToList();
            pairPicker.ItemsSource = sorted;

        }
```

Comment: So is your question actually the much less complicated "how do I check if a string ends with USDT"?

Comment: yes and show only those in the picker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  [EndsWith()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.endswith?view=net-5.0#System_String_EndsWith_System_String_)   as a condition inside of Linq [Where()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) method:

```
 var sorted = cryptoconverted.OrderBy(x => x.symbol).Where(x => x.symbol.EndsWith("USDT")).ToList();
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! I didnt know that was something i could do. It's really simple.